# Spring Boot/MVC/Tomcat error after running for a long time: Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm getting this error after the development server sits for a long time, overnight. It might be due to the computer going to sleep, but I don't think so. I'm not sure if this will happen in production, but it's a worrying sign. The console doesn't show any error. This shows in the browser, for basically any path, including `/error`.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu May 17 11:50:42 EDT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

There *is* an error page! The `/error` path should return

```
This is not a valid request
```

When I restart the app (CTRL+C, `mvn spring-boot:run`) then it works correctly. This is the simple error servlet

```
@RequestMapping("/error")
public void invalidRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    try {
        CustomLogger.info(TAG, "invalidRequest: ", "Method name: invalidRequest() invalid request from user");
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        response.getWriter().write("This is not a valid request");
```

Let me know if you want to see any particular settings or code.

Comment: did you use `spring boot actuator`

Comment: Paste the code of your entire RestController @Chloe

Comment: @SAM No it is not one of the JARs in my classpath. @-andrewbleme Can you be more specific? The entire REST controller is 870 lines and contains proprietary code.

Comment: `spring boot actuator` has some out of the box production-ready support. That will be a helpful one.

Comment: I need information: In development server, how do you start web app (build JAR, WAR, then deploy, or use mvn spring-boot:run, or else)?

Comment: @DoNhuVy Using `mvn spring-boot:run`

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if this will happen in production

**Production** and **development** are different. In development, webapp running over one night is too long, it will cause problem. But in production, there are maybe no problem.

In production, don't use

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Many option at the above command is optimization for **development phase**, and clearly, not optimization for **production phase** (For example: Logging level, many log at console screen, testing, hot refreshing, v.v..)

In production mode, there are two popular options:

(1) Using fat JAR, run command

```
java -jar target/*.jar
```

(2) Use tradition WAR, put WAR file on application server, then WAR file is automatically unzip on server (For example: Apache Tomcat)

Read more at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html